# Possible 3D printer nozzle jam?

Tags: monoprice-maker-select

Is this a jam? How do it fix it? There is a piece of filament stuck in the metal block (I have no idea what it is used for(other than mounting). When I heat up the extruder and try to extrude nothing happens.

Printer: Maker Select v2 (Wanhao Duplicator I3 Plus)

[image]

Image above is the hot-end with the filament feeding stepper motor removed.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: Need more information.  A nozzle jam is when the nozzle is obstructed, so that the filament won't extrude from the hole.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that there are parts removed? Could you provide an additional photo with an overview of the printer and optionally mention the hotend type. Please describe in more detail what we are looking at.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is the top of a Makerbot MK10-style hotend. It appears that the filament has snapped off at the entry of the heat break at the top of the cold end. The image below shows how the hotend is constructed, from top to bottom, brasss nozzle, heater element block, heat break (with PTFE liner, or not if it is an all metal hotend) and the cold end cooling block.

[image]

You indeed have a jam if an increased temperature cannot push the filament out. What you can try is to heat up the hotend (above the normal filament printing temperature, e.g. 10-20 °C higher; a too high temperature can cause filament to carbonize) with the feeder stepper removed pushing a 1.5 mm drill bit from the top of the heat break and see if you can push the obstruction out. If you have a fine needle or a specific nozzle cleaning tool, you could try from the nozzle opening. If not, you need to take the hotend apart and need to consider to buy some spare parts (at least a new PTFE liner if present), this is usually more simple than cleaning the small parts. If it is ABS filament you can use acetone to dissolve the filament, but for PLA/PETG there are no simple solvents.

The image below shows an exploded view of the assembly.

[image]

Comment: To remove filament in that spot, one can heat the printer, then insert a thin allan key (best one with a ball-adapter) or the drill bit with the drill-edge down, then shut off the printer. Once the temperature is down to 150 to 170 degrees, one can do a "cold pull" using the fallen key as an extension of the filament.